# Gravitational potential of a nearly spherical body

Tags: newtonian-gravity, terminology, potential, planets

In my book an equation is stated for the gravitational potential $V(r,\theta)$ of a nearly spherical body, such as the Earth. It says that the equation is derived using Laplace's equation though the derivation is not given and it contains the terms $J_0$, $J_2$, $J_3$, as well as the terms $P_0$, $P_1$, $P_2$:
$$V(r,\theta)=-\frac{GM}{r}\Big(J_0P_0-J_1\frac{a}{r}P_1(\cos{\theta})-J_2\frac{a^2}{r^2}P_2(\cos{\theta}) ...\Big)$$
As the derivation is not given, it is not clear to me at all  what the $J_i$ and $P_i$ terms stand for. It says that the $J_i$ terms represent the distribution of mass, but what does that mean? And what do the $P_i$ terms mean?

Comment: $P_i$'s are probably Legendre polynomials, and $J_i$'s are just model parameters (to be set/found for specific cases).

Comment: My guess is about the same as @Alexander  but I think the $J_i$ terms might be Bessel functions, rather than model parameters, any thoughts?

Comment: Apparently my guess was wrong.  The $J_i$ terms are indeed measured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $P_i$ terms are indeed Legender Polynomials.  I am no expert on this system, but apparently the $J_0$ term is typically taken to be 1.  The $J_1$ term is zero if the center of the coordinate system is the center of mass.  The $J_2$ term describes the ellipticity of the object.   I found quite a detailed discussion of the "nearly spherical mass potential" here:

http://www-gpsg.mit.edu/12.201_12.501/BOOK/chapter2.pdf

and the good news is the  author does appear to be somewhat of an expert on the matter, and includes some derivations.